# Bringing javascript block into php?

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I want to use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var checked = false;
        $('button.check-all').click(function() {
            checked = !checked;
            $('.checkbox-class').prop('checked', checked); // jQuery 1.6+
            if (checked) $(this).text('Uncheck All');
            else $(this).text('Check All');
        });
    })();
</script>
```

iside php code,

```
echo <<< CHECKALL

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var checked = false;
        $('button.check-all').click(function() {
        console.log("checked");
            checked = !checked;
            $('.permissionsCheckBox').prop('checked', checked); // jQuery 1.6+
            if (checked){ $(this).text('Uncheck All');}
            console.log("looopChecked");
            else { $(this).text('Check All');}
        });
    })();
</script>
CHECKALL;
```

But I'm getting a syntax error at `else { $(this).text('Check All');}`
and I'm not sure `$(this)` notation works for php javascript??

Comment: where is the php code?

Comment: Considering you're not using any PHP values within the Javascript, just end the PHP tags `?>` and do the Javascript. There is no need to have it in PHP.

Comment: @KartikA The 2nd piece of code is php, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Because you have this

```
console.log("looopChecked");
```

after the if condition.And after that you have the else condition which is not a valid one.The else part must be placed immediately after the if condition.So you must change this

```
if (checked){
   $(this).text('Uncheck All');
}
console.log("looopChecked");
else {
   $(this).text('Check All');
}
```

to this

```
if (checked){
   $(this).text('Uncheck All');
}
else {
   $(this).text('Check All');
}
```

And keep logging into the console either before of after the condition checking or do it either inside your if condition or inside the else condition will solve the error.

Answer (score 4):

You have a `console.log("looopChecked")` between an If and an Else statement

```
if (checked){ $(this).text('Uncheck All');}
console.log("looopChecked");
else { $(this).text('Check All');}
```

Must be

```
if (checked){ $(this).text('Uncheck All');}
else { $(this).text('Check All');}
```

Hint : ALWAYS indent your code. It will help yo to avoid such syntax errors.